# EntityFramework refuses to forget old columns

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, ef-database-first

I'm using EntityFramework 6.1.3, database-first. I am currently wishing I had chosen code-first...

I have a database with some tables. I've previously 
built my edmx off of these tables. Then I changed the type of a few columns and added a few columns. For instance, changing a `bit` column to an `int` column.

I try and update my model from the database, using `right-click -> Update Model from Database`.

It seems that no matter what I do, EF will only ever pick up the state of my database as it was when I created the edmx. Things I have tried:

1. Reopening Visual Studio
2. Rebuilding the project
3. Deleting and re-adding the entity (this is what most people say should work)
4. Searching the entire project for text references in xml or C# to my column while visual studio is closed and replacing them. (This seems to work at first but if I try to update from database again it writes over them)
5. Restarting SQL service
6. Restarting the machine
7. "Run Custom Tool" on all .tt files (shouldn't make a difference but what the hell)

When I right-click my entity and select "Table Mapping", it always always shows the old `bit` column on the left.

[image: mapping problem]

Here's my database table design:

[image: sql table design]

It might be of note that the entity is going off a view, not directly off of the table. But the view is literally a select * of the table as I am investigating this issue, and I have confirmed with powershell that the type returned by the view is an int:

```
PS> $conn = new-object data.sqlclient.SqlConnection("data source=localhost;initial catalog=dbname;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework")
PS> $conn.open()
PS> $query = $conn.createcommand()
PS> $query.commandtext = "select * from [dbname].[LocalCustom].[viewname]"
PS> $reader = $query.executereader()
PS> $reader.getschematable().rows[19]

ColumnName                      : ActiveMember
ColumnOrdinal                   : 19
ColumnSize                      : 4
NumericPrecision                : 10
NumericScale                    : 255
IsUnique                        : False
IsKey                           :
BaseServerName                  :
BaseCatalogName                 :
BaseColumnName                  : ActiveMember
BaseSchemaName                  :
BaseTableName                   :
DataType                        : System.Int32
AllowDBNull                     : False
ProviderType                    : 8
IsAliased                       :
IsExpression                    :
IsIdentity                      : False
IsAutoIncrement                 : False
IsRowVersion                    : False
IsHidden                        :
IsLong                          : False
IsReadOnly                      : False
ProviderSpecificDataType        : System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlInt32
DataTypeName                    : int
XmlSchemaCollectionDatabase     :
XmlSchemaCollectionOwningSchema :
XmlSchemaCollectionName         :
UdtAssemblyQualifiedName        :
NonVersionedProviderType        : 8
IsColumnSet                     : False
```

My MAIN QUESTION I have at this time is... **How does EF know that it used to be a `bit` type? Where is it storing this data??** Of course I would also like to know how to properly update the model using the UI without having to delete and re-add entities or whatever else I'm going to have to do to get it to update.

I'm pretty frustrated with EF :(

Comment: remove your `edmx` and create a new one.You can eventually manually modify the `CSDL` \ `SSDL`.

Comment: Not sure if this comment might help but do you think it might have something to do with the field not being allowed nulls and there actually being data in the table.

Comment: EDMX tools are picky when it comes to renaming or removing columns. Find the column in the XML and remove it.

Comment: I've tried a simple test on my side and ***it works expectedly***. After updating the model from database, I can see the `int` type (changed from `bit`) in the table mapping view. Looks like there is something on your side making it not working. It's of course not a public/wide problem of EF6

Comment: @hopeless: was your attempt based on a "select * " view of the modified object ?

Comment: @xum59 I don't use any query to check it. Just modify the column in database (be sure to close the table designer and all changes are applied on the database), then update the model from database normally. Then open the table mapping view (mapping details), I can see the column type (on left side) is changed to `int` (expectedly).

Comment: @hopeless: agreed. Now do the same thing where your entity maps to a "SELECT *" view of your table. When the table is updated, EF won't change the entity as the view has been updated.

Comment: @xum59 from the OP's question I did not see any where he mentioned the view is involved here? I thought he wanted to mean an actual table? Also if you mean view, then you can try openning SSMS, check the view inside `Views` folder, you'll see that the column there is still `bit` ***unless*** you re-create (alter) the view. So it's not a problem of EF, it's right in SSMS.

Comment: @hopeless: I just read carefully ;) "It might be of note that the entity is going off a view, not directly off of the table". Some expert may narrow the search but I think it's somehow related to _sys_ objects in the master db or something.

Comment: @xum59 yes, there should be some metadata stored together with the created view. The OP should know that this is not a problem of EF (he complained about EF - and I don't really like that because I'm addicted in EF) - it's just because of how view is stored in database.

Comment: EF database-first seems to be shit. I'm using code-first from now on because the tools suck. If I delete and recreate the entity, it should know to get the metadata from scratch. Plus I shouldn't have to delete and recreate the entity in the first  place

Comment: @Nacht: i don't agree, db-first works correctly. As my updated answer proves, your problem was at db level. There is absolutely no need to delete/rebuild the entities.

Comment: I thought my PowerShell would contradict that, but I suppose there's some difference between types returned in an actual query and types assigned to the view?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, just edit/update your view, even with no changes. EF doesn't update unmodified items.

As long as you haven't changed/updated the view but the underlying table(s), EF can't detect there's a need to change anything. I do believe this behavior is meant to prevent from a full rebuild of the model each time.

---

As the OP wished to understand "why", I made a few tests.

First, I created a table and a "SELECT *" view on it :

```
create table TableToChange(rowKey bigint IDENTITY(1,1) not null, myBitFlag bit null, myIntFlag int)
go
create view SelectStarOnChangingTable as SELECT * FROM TableToChange
go
```

Then I did a little check of the sys objects and columns that were created with :

```
select * 
from sys.all_objects AO 
    join sys.all_columns AC on AC.object_id=AO.object_id
where AO.object_id in (--insert your objet_ids here--)
```

Do some minor changes on the table object :

```
alter table TableToChange
drop column myBitFlag
go
alter table TableToChange
add myBitFlag int
go
```

If you run again the schema query, you'll notice that the updated column doesn't have the same type in the USER_TABLE row and the VIEW row (56 vs 104)

Altering the `SelectStarOnChangingTable` view without changes will force SQL Server to update.

We now have a culprit : SQL Server stores the view's column types preventing EF to update its model, even if the entity is rebuilt from scratch.

Comment: I will try this, but it doesn't answer my question how it knows what the table was like previously!

Comment: The EDMX file contains a Store Model that describes the DB objects. Then they are mapped to entities. If EF doesn't detect any changes in the underlying DB object, Store Model doesn't get updated and you end up with the "old" type. I'm no EF-cooking-expert so I won't try to expand further in that direction ;)

Comment: That seems to have worked1!!!!!!!!! You get a +1, but it sounds like you're saying the former state of the `ActiveMember` field being a `bit` is stored in the edmx file, but I checked there and the entire file did not contain any instances of the word "bit". In fact while my entities were deleted, it didn't contain anything from them.

Comment: While it may be interesting to find how VS, EF and DB track changes of the column types, the fact is that unmodified DB objects won't trigger update to the EF model. Let me know if you find who to blame ;)

Comment: Yes that does make some kind of sense. But at the same time if all references to the old database schema are deleted, it can make one feel insane to continue to see it appear. I'm sure the answer will be boring in the end but I would like to know how to force a refresh in the future. I'll probably mark yours as correct in the likely event that nobody answers this question in the next day or two.

Comment: hrm, i thought recreating the entire edmx _did_ work, but that was last time not this time, so I must not be remembering correctly

Comment: the query i did is `select * from sys.all_objects AO join sys.all_columns AC on AC.object_id = AO.object_id where AC.name = 'ActiveEmployer'` since I didn't know how to find the object_ids

Answer (score 15):

This is the case I often meet when using Entity Framework database-first. When you make some changes from the database, to update EF, you should:

1. Delete the modified table in .edmx
2. Re-add that table to your .edmx by `right-click -> Update Model from Database -> check that table`

Comment: this is what I do , but it is so slow in my very large schema, I wish there was an even quicker way